# How to make all the view appear

Tags: iphone, ipad, interface-builder

I am using Interface Builder to make some view layers as below , the view of file`s owner is pointed to the lowest view layer (the "view" on the first line), and this ViewController(showed in the picture) is added as a subview to the rootViewController :

[image: ,]

The problem is that I can only see the Grid View , but I can not see the view with pageControl:

[image]

blue:rootview  green:the view just said , can not see the red and yellow view the pic showed above, you can see the green margin for it.

I just thought , on Interface Builder, what you put is what you will see , right? Why the view with pageControl did not appear? how to fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the green view is being placed above the yellow one. If I understand correctly both views are subviews of 'View'? Try in viewDidLoad [view bringSubviewToFront:pageControl] to see if that is indeed the problem or not.